# Unity4XC plug-in error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm using Unity 4.6 and Xcode. After updating Xcode to 7.1 version I'm getting this error while trying to run build for iphone:

**Unexpected code bundle “Unity4XC.xcplugin”**
The “Unity4XC.xcplugin” code bundle is not provided by Apple. Loading code not provided by Apple can have a negative effect on the safety and stability of Xcode or related tools.

I clicked on "Load Bundle".

Since then I'm getting this error:

**Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the Unity4XC plug-in.**
Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

I tried to open the project from within the Xcode program and it still not working.

If I try to open the project manually I get this error in xcode:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there a connection to the problem?

What should try to do now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's currently a known issue:

http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-build-and-run-doesnt-work-with-xcode-7-and-7-dot-1